# How to avoid duplicate plugin declarations in each build script?

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle build that invokes various other gradle scripts, using `apply from`. Both the main `build.gradle` and each of the sub-scripts make use of the same build script plugin (the gradle-cargo-plugin, specifically).

The only way I've managed to get this to work is to repeat the declaration of the plugin in each script:

`build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-cargo-plugin:1.5.1'
    }
}

apply from: 'other.gradle'

// do something with the cargo plugin
```

`other.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-cargo-plugin:1.5.1'
    }
}

// do something else with the cargo plugin
```

As you can see, the `buildscript` section is repeated in each script. Changing that dependency becomes tedious and error-prone, but the sub-script don't inherit the dependency from the main `build.gradle`.

Is there a way to clean this up, either by allowing the invoked scripts to inherit the `buildscript` dependency, or a different way to delegate to the sub-scripts instead of using `apply from`?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me with Gradle 2.1. Build scripts declared in a `build.gradle`'s `buildscript` block are visible in script plugins.

Plugins in the new plugin portal (http://plugins.gradle.org/) can be applied in a single line, and don't require a `buildscript` block (with Gradle 2.1 and higher).

Comment: I am of the opinion that this is not the answer. Of course the OPs duplicated buildscript in two files will work. But OP was asking a solution where he can have a single declaration of build dependencies from which other gradle script files can inherit from. Its not about the visibility of buildscript from the plugins